# Need to add a list of in JSON via JSON Patch

Tags: json, json-patch, json-path-expression, fastjsonpatch

I have been reading about JSON Patch. However, I cannot find a solution to my problem.
I have a JSON which I need to add a list.

For example:

```
{
  "orders": "food"
}
```

I need to inject this list of items below the orders attribute.

```
{
  "items": [
  {
   "item": "ORD-X11",
   "buyer": "BY-001-001",
   "date": "060220"
  }
 ]
}
```

So the expected result is:

```
{
  "orders": "food"
  "items": [
  {
   "item": "ORD-X11",
   "buyer": "BY-001-001",
   "date": "060220"
  }
 ]
}
```

This is my code in JSON Patch:

```
{"op": "add", "path": "/items",
                      "value": {}
                      }
{"op": "add", "path": "/items/0",
                      "value": {"item": "ORD-X11"}
                      }
{"op": "add", "path": "/items/0",
                      "value": {"buyer": "BY-001-001"}
                      }
{"op": "add", "path": "/items/0",
                      "value": {"date": "060220"}
                      }
```

Error is appearing that the doc path is missing "/items" which I am trying to add.

Answer (score 1):

I've also only recently run into JSON-Patch and found this question interesting; after reading the [fast-json-patch docs](https://github.com/Starcounter-Jack/JSON-Patch) and with some trial and error I came up with this solution to your problem:

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import * as jsonpatch from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fast-json-patch@3.0.0-1/index.mjs';
  import { applyOperation } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fast-json-patch@3.0.0-1/index.mjs';
  
  var document = {"orders": "food"};
  var patch = [
      {"op": "add", "path": "/items",
          "value": [{"item": "ORD-X11","buyer": "BY-001-001","date": "060220"}]
      }
  ];
  document = jsonpatch.applyPatch(document, patch).newDocument;
  console.log(document);
</script>
```

As you can see, we can patch the entire sub-object at once. Lovely.